# Perlcritic not recognising code that has been tidied

Tags: perl, perl-critic, perl-tidy

I'm using [perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlcritic) with [perltidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltidy) and while the other rules are applied, I'm, getting the following error message:

```
Code is not tidy at line 1, near 'package MyPackage;'.
```

I've run perltidy to tidy the code but I am still getting the problem. In the .perlcriticrc file I've added the following rule with the path to .perltidyrc file.

```
[CodeLayout::RequireTidyCode]
perltidyrc = /path/to/.perltidyrc
```

I'm running perlcritic like this:

```
perlcritic --profile .perlcriticrc file.pm
```

I'm sure that perlcritic is using the rc file as I'm able to turn rules on and off by ammending the file content. I'm also sure that perltidy is using the correct rc file in the same way.

How can I prevent this error without disabling the RequireTidyCode rule?

I've added an example to recreate the problem by cutting the actual files down to the minimum where I'm still getting the error. This is how I'm running it:

```
cd /tmp
perltidy -b -nst TestCritic.pm
perlcritic --profile /tmp/.perlcriticrc /tmp/TestCritic.pm
```

The first line of the critic output is:

```
Code is not tidy at line 1, near 'package TestCritic;'.
```

These are the files:

**TestCritic.pm**

```
package TestCritic;

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;

    my $config;
    my $service_name;

    if ( defined $ENV{MYVAR} ) {
        if ( $ENV{MYVAR} eq 'TESTVAL' ) {
            $config       = { Config => { file => '/tmp/tmp.txt' } };
            $service_name = 'TestCritic.' . $$;
        }
    }
}

1;
```

**.perltidyrc**

```
-pbp
-lp
-bar
-l=120
-nolc
-vmll
-cti=1
-pt=0
-vt=0
-vtc=0
```

**.perlcriticrc**

```
# Show all errors
severity = 1
verbose = 11
theme = core + pbp + bugs + maintenance + cosmetic + complexity + security + tests
exclude = Subroutines::ProhibitCallsToUndeclaredSubs
```

Versions are:
perlcritic v1.132
perltidy v20181120

Thanks,

Comment: When you ran perltidy, did you tell it to modify your code in place with [`-backup-and-modify-in-place`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/bin/perltidy#-b,-backup-and-modify-in-place)?

Comment: Yes, I've used that. I've also written the critic output to a new file and diffed them to make sure it's working and they are the same.

Comment: In that case, I can't reproduce your problem. Could you add a short, self-contained example that other people can run?

Comment: I've included an example perl file, perlcriticrc and perltidy rc which can be used to recreate the problem.

Comment: On the off-chance, are you using some particular editors or a code management system? See [this bug](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/issues/2829) for Komodo.  (I can't reproduce either)

Comment: I'm using VS Code but I get the problem when running on the command line too.

Answer (score 1):

Put ...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

... at the top of the file, before the package declaration, then you should be good.

Tested against perlcritic v1.130

Comment: I'm getting the same problem: `perltidy had errors!! at line 1, near 'use strict;'.`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem with the configuration given in your question, including the addition of `[CodeLayout::RequireTidyCode]`, using perlcritic v1.130 and perltidy v20170521. The critic complains about a few things, but "perltidy had errors" is not one of them.